# What is mongoose actually opening here?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am in the beginning stages of learning the MEAN stack.

I've created my first Node app, using mongoose and mongodb.

In my node.js code, I have the following:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meantest1');
```

I can create documents and find them just fine, however, I'm not entirely sure where it's storing the data?

```
app.get('/api/test', function (req, res) {
    test.create({
        name: "Joe Schmo"
    }, function() {
        test.find(function (err, tests) {
            res.json(tests);
        })
    });
})
```

In the mongo shell, if I execute

```
use meantest1
db.test.find()
```

it returns data I entered in the shell, but nothing from my app.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Also, is there a better app for querying mongo than the shell??

Comment: Mongoose pluralizes the names of your collections, unless you explicitly give it a name. Try `db.tests.find()`.

Comment: That was exactly it!  Post as the answer and I'll mark as such.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose automatically pluralizes collection names when you register a model. In your case the model name of `Test` would be converted to the collection name of `tests`.

If you want to prevent pluralization, or you need to attach your model to an existing collection that's not pluralized, you may pass the collection name as a third argument to the `mongoose.model` method:

```
mongoose.model('Test', testSchema, 'test');
```